# Como simular que se presiona 2 div al mismo tiempo, los cuales ya tiene un evento ondblclick asignado cada uno

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, css3

mi duda es la siguiente, me gustaría presionar los div 1 y 2 , simulando que se presionan los 2 al mismo tiempo, para poder mostrar los otros div que están ocultos y a su ves, ocultar div 1 y 2, no se si se pude hacer eso con javascript o jquery, mi restricción es que ya tienen ondblclick, pero la combinación de los div presionados no se como elaborarla.
el efecto de mantenerlo presionado creo que es con css. 
por el momento estoy probando de esta forma.

```
  <h2>simulando la combinacion de 2 div precionados</h2>
<div id="div1">
    <div class="l_power1" id="l_power1" ondblclick="boton1()">1</div>
    <div class="r_power2" id="r_power2" ondblclick="boton2()">2</div>

</div>
<div style="display: none;" id="div-nuevo">

    <div class="l_power3" id="l_power3" onclick="boton1()">nuevo div3</div>
    <div class="r_power4" id="r_power4" onclick="">nuevo div4</div>
    <div class="r_power5" id="r_power5" onclick="">nuevo div5</div>
    <div class="l_power6" id="l_power6" onclick="">nuevo div5</div>
</div>
```

css se repite para todos los div, solo se cambia left por otro valor para mostrar el div siguiente

```
      .l_power1{
    border: 1px solid black;
    position:absolute;
    left:6.6em;
    top:3.5em;
    height:4.5em;
    width:0.8em;
    background:#e4e4e4;
    border-radius: 6px;

}
```

script

```
 function boton1() {

        if (document.getElementById('l_power1').innerHTML == '.') {
            document.getElementById('l_power1').innerHTML = '';
            document.getElementById('l_power1').style.backgroundColor = 'black';

        } else {
            cambiaVisibilidad3();
            document.getElementById('l_power1').innerHTML = '.';
            document.getElementById('l_power1').style.backgroundColor = '#e4e4e4';
        } 
    }

function cambiaVisibilidad3() {
    var div1 = document.getElementById('div1');
    var div2 = document.getElementById('div-nuevo');

    if(div2.style.display ==='block'){  
        div2.style.display = 'none';
        div1.style.display = 'block';
    }else{
       div2.style.display = 'block';
       div1.style.display = 'none';

    } 
}
```

Comment: Entiendo que quieres simular dos clicks(al botón 1 y 2 al mismo tiempo) lo que no me queda claro es *como lo quieres simular?* o como quieres que detone esa acción... Dando click en otra parte? Usando eventos?... Como? Simular el onclick, si no estas trabajando con tiempos lo podrías hacer invocando los eventos onclick de ambos botones en una sola función. O haciendo que las dos funciones sean asíncronas pero eso va depender de mas detalles..

Comment: muy buenas @VíctorHugoTirado, lo que estoy simulando es en si un reloj, cuando yo presiono botón 1 me genera el evento alarma, si yo presiono botón 2, me genera el modo fecha, pero en los relojes si presionamos ambos botones al mismo tiempo genera un nuevo evento, este evento es el que quiero simular, se me vino algo a la cabeza algo de los tiempos como me comentaste, asumiendo que en el boton 2 tenga un objeto que este esperando el segundo click en boton 1, y si no hay otro click mostraría el evento de boton 1, no se si me explique bien.

Comment: @BernalHD Creo que hacer clic en dos botones a la vez es fisicamente imposible. ¿Has pensado en hacer un solo clic sostenido en alguno de los dos botones para hacer dicha funcionalidad? Es mucho más simple de simular y fisicamente posible :P

Comment: me gustaría ver tu idea, yo por el momento estoy probando con keycode y keydown, al presionar las 2 teclas en teoría me funcionaria, pero en la practica no me sale, subiré el código para que lo veamos con mas detalle.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/danHD/sexbwLrj/2/
aqui es donde he estado intentando, como puedes ver, no me funciona, no se que me falta.